# Why i am not able to render the rc-slider and its label appear in a single row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I  need to add a label to the rc-slider in the same row and i used bootstrap grid but the label and the slider appears in two rows.

```
 <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
          Label:
      </div>
      <div className="col">
      <Slider value={this.props.sample} 
          onChange={this.onSliderChange} 
          onAfterChange={this.onAfterChange}
          defaultValue={13}
      />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the row inside a div with the `container` class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col">
      Label:
    </div>
    <div className="col">
      <Slider value={this.props.sample} onChange={this.onSliderChange} onAfterChange={this.onAfterChange} defaultValue={13} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info in the grid documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You must be having the issue with including the bootstrap, check in your code is bootstrap is loading in your devtools network tab. After confirming that, change the className of the columns class in bootstrap. like below. This should work for you.

```html
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-lg-1">
    Label
  </div>
  <div className="col-lg-11">
    <Slider
      value={10}
      onChange={this.onSliderChange}
      onAfterChange={this.onAfterChange}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```